# Bucle for números aleatorios

Tags: java, loops

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio, en el cual se me pide generar unos números aleatorios para crear una combinación para la primitiva. Como condición es que cada número salga de un bucle for, os pongo mi planteamiento a continuación, el problema es que se me repiten los números. Creo que no estoy planteando mal la "condición".

```
public class Ejer_5_UD_4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
    int n5;
    int n6;
    int n7;
    int reintegro;

    System.out.print("Combinación de la primitiva: ");

    for (n1 = 1; n1 <= 1; n1++) {
        n1 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n1 + ",");
    }

    for (n2 = 1; n2 >= 1 & n2 != n1; n2++) {
        n2 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n2 + ",");
    }

    for (n3 = 1; n3 <= 1 & n3 != n1 & n3 !=n2; n3++) {
        n3 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n3 + ",");
    }

    for (n4 = 1; n4 <= 1 & n4 != n1 & n4 != n2 & n4!=n3; n4++) {
        n4 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n4 + ",");
    }

    for (n5 = 1; n5 <= 1 & n5 != n1 & n5!=n2 & n5!=n3 & n5!=n4; n5++) {
        n5 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n5 + ",");
    }

    for (n6 = 1; n6 <= 1 & n6 != n1 & n6!=n2 & n6!=n3 & n6!=n4 & n6!=n5; n6++) {
        n6 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.print(n6);
    }

    for (n7 = 1; n7 <= 1 & n7 != n1 & n7!=n2 & n7!=n3 & n7!=n4 & n7!=n5 & n7!=n6; n7++) {
        n7 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
        System.out.println("\nEl número complementario es: " + n7 );            
    }

    reintegro = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    System.out.println("Reintegro: " + reintegro);

}
```

}

Es obligatorio usar el bucle `for` para resolver el problema, la estructura que tengo que plantear es un bucle `for` para cada número, lo cual me hace pensar que el planteamiento está bien pero hay algo que se me escapa.

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo exactamente cuál es la servidumbre que te han puesto. ¿Qué debe cumplir cada `for`? Si no dices nada más puedes usar mi respuesta y cada for sería `for(;numeros.size() < 1;)` para el primero, `for(;numeros.size() < 2;)` para el segundo y así hasta el séptimo.

Answer (score 2):

Para que no te pase lo de los números repetidos es mejor usar un `Set` ya que no permita repeticiones. Tampoco te queda elegante el código, reutilizas poco y haces muchas variables. Mi solución para tí es esta:

```
Set<Integer> numeros = new HashSet<>();

for(;numeros.size() < 7;) {
    int numero = (int) (Math.random()*49) + 1;
    if(!numeros.add(numero))
        System.out.println(numero + " descartado por estar repetido.");            
}

int reintegro = (int)(Math.random()*10);

System.out.println("Los números escogidos son: " + numeros);
System.out.println("El número complementario es: " + reintegro);
```

La salida que me ha dado es:

> 45 descartado por estar repetido.
>   32 descartado por estar repetido.
>   Los números escogidos son: [32, 1, 19, 6, 38, 40, 45]
>   El número complementario es: 5

Answer (score 0):

De partida cuando pones la condición en el `for` para que no se repitan debes hacerlo con doble `&` para generar la expresión lógica `and`. Por lo tanto cambia `&` por `&&`.

De todas maneras refactorizaría tu código haciendo algo como esto:

```
Integer nRandom = null;
Integer count = 0;
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (count < 7) {
  nRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
  if (numeros.indexOf(nRandom) < 0) {
      numeros.add(nRandom);
      count++;
  }
}

System.out.println(numeros);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el primer caso no importa cual es primer número.

```
    for (n1 = 1; n1 <= 1; n1++) {
       n1 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
       System.out.print(n1 + ",");
    }
```

pero para los otros si importa que número son los anteriores, tempondre el caso del tercero pero es la misma idea para los otros(Esto solo devuelve numeros positivos).

```
    for (n3 = 1; n3 >= 1; n3++) {
       n3 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
       if(n3 != n1 && n3 != n2){
              System.out.print(n3 + ",");
              break;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En Kotlin para generar un lista de números enteros que se generen aleatoriamente del 1 a 99, sin repetirse

```kotlin
fun makeRndIntList(size : Int = 5 ) : List<Int> {
    val s = HashSet<Int>(size)
    while (s.size < size) {
        s += makeRnd( (1..99).random() )
    }
    return s.shuffled()
}
```

Su uso quieres 10 números aleatorios

```kotlin
val arr = makeRndIntList(10)
for (element in arr) {
   println(element)
}
/*
17
48
45
1
43
87
100
96
5
*/
```